# How to parametrize the curves

Tags: analytic-geometry, parametrization

I have to parametrize the curve of intersection of 2 surfaces. The surfaces are:

$$y = x,$$

$$z^2 + y^2 = 25.$$

1. Set the second equation to

$$y^2 = 25 - z^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

According to the second equation,

$$
z^2 + y^2 = 25,
$$

one may use a parametrization: for $t \in [0, 2\pi]$,

$$
\begin{aligned}
y &= 5\cos{t} \\
z &= 5\sin{t} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $y = x$,

$$
\gamma(t) = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &= 5\cos{t} \\
y &= 5\cos{t} \\
z &= 5\sin{t} \\
\end{aligned}
\right.\quad t \in [0, 2\pi].
$$